# MySQL query with many joins taking too long to execute

Tags: mysql, query-optimization

I have this query and it is taking too long to load(about 40 seconds).

```
SELECT
  `auxiliary_table_2`.`entry_id`,
  `auxiliary_table_2`. `name`,
  COUNT(`auxiliary_table_2`.`entry_id`) AS `auxiliary_table_2_count`
FROM (SELECT
    `data_table`.*
      FROM `data_table`
    LEFT JOIN `exp_channels`
      ON `exp_channels`.`channel_id` = `data_table`.`channel_id`
    LEFT JOIN `exp_channel_titles`
      ON `exp_channel_titles`.`entry_id` = `data_table`.`entry_id`
      WHERE `exp_channels`.`channel_name` = 'main_table'
      AND `exp_channel_titles`.`status` = 'open'
      GROUP BY `data_table`.`entry_id`) AS `main_table`
  JOIN `mapping_table` AS `mapping_table_1`
    ON `mapping_table_1`.`rel_id` = `main_table`.`field_id_9`
  JOIN (SELECT
      `data_table`.`entry_id`,
      `data_table`.`field_id_8`       AS `name`
    FROM `data_table`
      LEFT JOIN `exp_channels`
        ON `exp_channels`.`channel_id` = `data_table`.`channel_id`
    WHERE `exp_channels`.`channel_name` = 'auxiliary_table_channel_name_1'
    GROUP BY `data_table`.`entry_id`) AS `auxiliary_table_1`
    ON `auxiliary_table_1`.`entry_id` = `mapping_table_1`.`rel_child_id`
  JOIN `mapping_table` AS `mapping_table_2`
    ON `mapping_table_2`.`rel_id` = `main_table`.`field_id_39`
  JOIN (SELECT
      `data_table`.`entry_id`,
      `data_table`.`field_id_38`      AS `name`
    FROM `data_table`
      LEFT JOIN `exp_channels`
        ON `exp_channels`.`channel_id` = `data_table`.`channel_id`
    WHERE `exp_channels`.`channel_name` = 'auxiliary_table_channel_name_2'
    GROUP BY `data_table`.`entry_id`) AS `auxiliary_table_2`
    ON `auxiliary_table_2`.`entry_id` = `mapping_table_2`.`rel_child_id`
  JOIN `mapping_table` AS `mapping_table_3`
    ON `mapping_table_3`.`rel_id` = `main_table`.`field_id_5`
  JOIN (SELECT
      `data_table`.`entry_id`,
      `data_table`.`field_id_1`       AS `name`
    FROM `data_table`
      LEFT JOIN `exp_channels`
        ON `exp_channels`.`channel_id` = `data_table`.`channel_id`
    WHERE `exp_channels`.`channel_name` = 'auxiliary_table_channel_name_3'
    GROUP BY `data_table`.`entry_id`) AS `auxiliary_table_3`
    ON `auxiliary_table_3`.`entry_id` = `mapping_table_3`.`rel_child_id`
  JOIN `mapping_table` AS `mapping_table_4`
    ON `mapping_table_4`.`rel_id` = `main_table`.`field_id_16`
  JOIN (SELECT
      `data_table`.`entry_id`,
      `data_table`.`field_id_18`      AS `name`
    FROM `data_table`
      LEFT JOIN `exp_channels`
        ON `exp_channels`.`channel_id` = `data_table`.`channel_id`
    WHERE `exp_channels`.`channel_name` = 'auxiliary_table_channel_name_4'
    GROUP BY `data_table`.`entry_id`) AS `auxiliary_table_4`
    ON `auxiliary_table_4`.`entry_id` = `mapping_table_4`.`rel_child_id`
  JOIN `mapping_table` AS `mapping_table_5`
    ON `mapping_table_5`.`rel_id` = `main_table`.`field_id_49`
  JOIN (SELECT
      `data_table`.`entry_id`,
      `data_table`.`field_id_48`      AS `name`
    FROM `data_table`
      LEFT JOIN `exp_channels`
        ON `exp_channels`.`channel_id` = `data_table`.`channel_id`
    WHERE `exp_channels`.`channel_name` = 'auxiliary_table_channel_name_5'
    GROUP BY `data_table`.`entry_id`) AS `auxiliary_table_5`
    ON `auxiliary_table_5`.`entry_id` = `mapping_table_5`.`rel_child_id`
GROUP BY `auxiliary_table_2`.`entry_id`
```

The gist of it is that `data_table` has auxiliary data in the auxiliary tables which are mapped via the mapping table. `main_table` is a just a filtered data table.

Is there something here that may have cause it to run slow?

`data_table` has only a small amount of rows(about 200+) so I assume that this is a query problem.

Here is the EXPLAIN results

```
id  select_type     table           type    possible_keys           key             key_len     ref                                     rows        Extra 
1   PRIMARY     <derived4>          ALL     NULL                    NULL            NULL        NULL                                    3           Using temporary; Using filesort
1   PRIMARY     <derived6>          ALL     NULL                    NULL            NULL        NULL                                    5           Using join buffer
1   PRIMARY     <derived7>          ALL     NULL                    NULL            NULL        NULL                                    6           Using join buffer
1   PRIMARY     <derived3>          ALL     NULL                    NULL            NULL        NULL                                    21          Using join buffer
1   PRIMARY     <derived2>          ALL     NULL                    NULL            NULL        NULL                                    20          Using join buffer
1   PRIMARY     <derived5>          ALL     NULL                    NULL            NULL        NULL                                    143         Using join buffer
1   PRIMARY     auxiliary_table_1   eq_ref  PRIMARY,rel_child_id    PRIMARY         4           main_table.field_id_9                   1           Using where
1   PRIMARY     auxiliary_table_2   eq_ref  PRIMARY,rel_child_id    PRIMARY         4           main_table.field_id_39                  1           Using where
1   PRIMARY     auxiliary_table_3   eq_ref  PRIMARY,rel_child_id    PRIMARY         4           main_table.field_id_5                   1           Using where
1   PRIMARY     auxiliary_table_4   eq_ref  PRIMARY,rel_child_id    PRIMARY         4           main_table.field_id_16                  1           Using where
1   PRIMARY     auxiliary_table_5   eq_ref  PRIMARY,rel_child_id    PRIMARY         4           main_table.field_id_49                  1           Using where
7   DERIVED     exp_channels        ref     PRIMARY,channel_name    channel_name    122                                                 1           Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
7   DERIVED     exp_channel_data    ref     channel_id              channel_id      4           devthree_ee.exp_channels.channel_id     17  
6   DERIVED     exp_channels        ref     PRIMARY,channel_name    channel_name    122                                                 1           Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
6   DERIVED     exp_channel_data    ref     channel_id              channel_id      4           devthree_ee.exp_channels.channel_id     17  
5   DERIVED     exp_channels        ref     PRIMARY,channel_name    channel_name    122                                                 1           Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
5   DERIVED     exp_channel_data    ref     channel_id              channel_id      4           devthree_ee.exp_channels.channel_id     17  
4   DERIVED     exp_channels        ref     PRIMARY,channel_name    channel_name    122                                                 1           Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
4   DERIVED     exp_channel_data    ref     channel_id              channel_id      4           devthree_ee.exp_channels.channel_id     17  
3   DERIVED     exp_channels        ref     PRIMARY,channel_name    channel_name    122                                                 1           Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
3   DERIVED     exp_channel_data    ref     channel_id              channel_id      4           devthree_ee.exp_channels.channel_id     17  
2   DERIVED     exp_channels        ref     PRIMARY,channel_name    channel_name    122                                                 1           Using where; Using temporary; Using filesort
2   DERIVED     exp_channel_data    ref     PRIMARY,channel_id      channel_id      4           devthree_ee.exp_channels.channel_id     17  
2   DERIVED     exp_channel_titles  eq_ref  PRIMARY,status          PRIMARY         4           devthree_ee.exp_channel_data.entry_id   1           Using where
```

MYSQL VERSION:

I am using MySQL 5.1.66-cll

TABLES:

data_table

```
#   Name        Type        Collation       Attributes      Null    Default Extra
1   entry_id    int(10)                     UNSIGNED        No      None        
2   site_id     int(4)                      UNSIGNED        No      1       
3   channel_id  int(4)                      UNSIGNED        No      None        
4   field_id_1  text        utf8_general_ci                 Yes     NULL        
5   field_ft_1  tinytext    utf8_general_ci                 Yes     NULL        
6   field_id_2  text        utf8_general_ci                 Yes     NULL        
7   field_ft_2  tinytext    utf8_general_ci                 Yes     NULL        
8   field_id_3  text        utf8_general_ci                 Yes     NULL        
9   field_ft_3  tinytext    utf8_general_ci                 Yes     NULL        
10  field_id_4  int(11)                                     Yes     0       
11  field_ft_4  tinytext    utf8_general_ci                 Yes     NULL        
12  field_id_5  int(10)                                     Yes     0       
13  field_ft_5  tinytext    utf8_general_ci                 Yes     NULL        
14  field_id_6  text        utf8_general_ci                 Yes     NULL
.....
```

mapping_table

```
#   Name                Type        Collation       Attributes      Null    Default     Extra   
1   rel_id              int(6)                      UNSIGNED        No      None        AUTO_INCREMENT
2   rel_parent_id       int(10)                                     No      0           
3   rel_child_id        int(10)                                     No      0           
4   rel_type            varchar(12) utf8_general_ci                 No      None        
5   rel_data            mediumtext  utf8_general_ci                 No      None        
6   reverse_rel_data    mediumtext  utf8_general_ci                 No      None
```

P.S. I have replaced the table names with generic names for anonymity purposes.

Comment: Can you please provide the result of `EXPLAIN SELECT ...`.

Comment: In addition to EXPLAIN, please tell what's your MySQL version.

Comment: Also consider rewriting your query with just joins and no subqueries. It's usually much easier to optimize such queries.

Comment: I have added the explain results. @ArtemGoutsoul Can you post a simple example as an answer?

Comment: Why do you have `GROUP BY` in the subqueries?

Comment: @ypercube to make sure I get unique results

Comment: They may be unique but they are probably not deterministic, the way the query is written (unless `data_table.entry_id` is the primary key of that table). Please add in the question, the (3) tables' definitions (the output of `SHOW CREATE TABLE tablename`).

Comment: @ypercube I think you are right. But what if I just remove it? Is it necessary?

Comment: Without the tables structure, I don't know.

Comment: Intead of this complex query please provide sameple data tables tructures and desired out. People might be able to present optimized query

Comment: I included the tabl structure of `data table` and `mapping_table`

Comment: You only need the 'group by' when using aggregated functions. i.e. not in the sub queries where aggregated functions are not being used.

Comment: Ok, I removed the GROUP BY inside the sub queries. But I don't think it solved anything.

Comment: Well, your EXPLAIN does show that the number of rows that has to be potentially read is enormous! Honestly without properly knowing what you are trying to do optimizing such an arcane query with multiple subqueries is a bit tough. Can you replace all subqueries with plain left joins? the best case is if the joins are using indexed columns in joined conditions. If you need to count some unique rows you can use COUNT(DISTINCT column_name).

Comment: Okay, I replaced the JOIN with LEFT JOIN and it suddenly became fast! Can you explain why?